# NPM start 'cannot find module'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

When I try the command `npm start` the console runs `npm install` and returns this error:

```
> npm@6.4.1 prepare C:\Users\Aristophanes
> node bin/npm-cli.js --no-audit --no-timing prune --prefix=. --no-global && rimraf test/*/*/node_modules && make -j4 doc

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Aristophanes\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:587:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:513:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:760:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:308:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:878:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! npm@6.4.1 prepare: `node bin/npm-cli.js --no-audit --no-timing prune --prefix=. --no-global && rimraf test/*/*/node_modules && make -j4 doc`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the npm@6.4.1 prepare script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Full log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/de0369plkz8w2ir/2018-11-10T07_56_03_314Z-debug.log?dl=0

Can anyone explain the `Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Aristophanes\bin\npm-cli.js'` error? In the directory `C:\Users\Aristophanes\bin\` I only have these files:

```
create-react-native-app 
create-react-native-app.cmd
```

The `npm-cli.js` file it's looking for is actually located in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js`

Does anyone have a suggestion to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Is C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\ in your PATH?

Comment: I had the same issue. Solution to this issue fixed it.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438781/cannot-find-module-c-node-modules-npm-bin-npm-cli-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438781/cannot-find-module-c-node-modules-npm-bin-npm-cli-js)