# Cannot find module 'C:\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

Tags: node.js, npm, loopback

I download loopback project from github  and trying to run it . When I type npm start I am getting following errors in console window .

```
 C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\Desktop\loop4\loopback4-example-shopping> npm start

> loopback4-example-shopping-monorepo@1.0.0 prestart C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\Desktop\loop4\loopback4-example-shopping
> npm run build


> loopback4-example-shopping-monorepo@1.0.0 build C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\Desktop\loop4\loopback4-example-shopping
> lerna run build

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:839:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you doing "npm install" command before npm start?

Any project you are cloning from git it won't have node_modules(which is having necessary library to run that application).

While "npm install" command, it will download all the required libraries based on your package.json/package-lock.json.

**If already you run "npm install", you can fix this issue using below command**

> npm i npm-cli --save

Comment: You can find the nodejs existing project running setup here https://weaintplastic.github.io/web-development-field-guide/Development/Frontend_Development/Setting_up_your_project/Setup_Dependency_Managers/Node_Package_Manager/Initialize_NPM_on_an_existing_project.html

Comment: Every project I want to run having this issue . I followed the instructions npm install i or npm install then npm start . This errors did not goes away . I tried to change the change the variable from setting , reinstall it node js. But sorry to say did not work . I am stuck on this issue

Comment: Just remove package-lock.json and node_module folder(if you have already) from your project and do "npm install" once. May this issue will resolve in this step

Answer (score 0):

You need to install typescript locally.

```
yarn global add typescript
```